# Working with elements "diagram properties" in script

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have an my own MDG, consist of several elements. I need change view of those elements when its placed at different diagram. There is a mechanism called "user-selected settings" in MDG and I use its to change view of elements (e.g. via shape script function "HasProp" ). But for several reason I need to change diagram property for element via script. Are there any way to work with diagram property for element within script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible but a bit tricky. First of all you need to get hold of the right diagram's table data stored in `t_diagram`. Issue a SQL like

```
SELECT StyleEx FROM t_diagram WHERE Diagram_ID = <theID>
```

Of course `<theID>` must be the diagram id of the diagram. Now you can use some string operations. Here's what my test diagram brought:

> ExcludeRTF=0;DocAll=0;HideQuals=0;AttPkg=1;ShowTests=0;ShowMaint=0;SuppressFOC=1;MatrixActive=0;SwimlanesActive=1;KanbanActive=0;MatrixLineWidth=1;MatrixLineClr=0;MatrixLocked=0;TConnectorNotation=UML 2.1;TExplicitNavigability=0;AdvancedElementProps=1;AdvancedFeatureProps=1;AdvancedConnectorProps=1;m_bElementClassifier=1;ProfileData=;MDGDgm=VW VA Functional 3::Use case activity;STBLDgm=;ShowNotes=0;OPTIONS_9CEFE070=Structure=1:;VisibleAttributeDetail=0;ShowOpRetType=1;SuppressBrackets=0;SuppConnectorLabels=0;PrintPageHeadFoot=0;ShowAsList=0;SuppressedCompartments=;Theme=:119;SaveTag=79E21B13;;

which is a CSV at its best. See the

```
OPTIONS_9CEFE070=Structure=1:;
```

which actually encodes the diagram properties. Here it's just one with the name `Structure` and its value is set to 1. The `9CEFE070`  refers to the GUID the diagram object. Of course not directly.

So find the diagram objects of the diagram itself with

```
SELECT Object_ID, ObjectStyle FROM t_diagramobjects
```

The `Object_ID` is for identifying the object behind (you might use a join to get needed information). And the `ObjectStlye` contains something like (from my test)

```
DUID=9CEFE070;HideIcon=0;
```

And there you have that hex string. Now you know that this one object has a diagram property set.

You should issue some queries manually to get familiar with that.

Now, to set a property, you "just" have to find the `DUID` from the diagram object of the diagram (just use the query above). Now you can add that `OPTIONS_<duid>` part or in case it already exists you need to modify it with according string operations. Finally you need to update the diagram table with

```
Repository.Execute("UPDATE t_diagram SET StyleEx = `<new string>` WHERE diagram_id = <theID>")
```

Note that this is an undocumented operation and you get

a) no support and
b) can easily clobber your whole model which is
c) the reason for a).

Have a backup!

Comment: It's not yet in my Inside book but I'll add that soon. My EA enthusiasm is a bit down...